# Issue updating a record with SQL / PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, record

I am very new to PHP. Apologies if this is an elementary question.

I am trying to update a record using PHP / SQL. I have googled this error, but am unable to determine the problem out of the context of my code:

> An error occured: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Here is my function:

```
function updateTeam($val) {

  global $server, $db, $dbUser, $dbKey, $message;

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $server . ";dbname=" . $db, $dbUser, $dbKey);
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Team SET teamName=:teamName, teamLogo=:teamLogo, WHERE teamID=" . $val);

    $sql -> bindValue(":teamID", $_POST["teamID"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":teamName", $_POST["teamName"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":teamLogo", $_POST["teamLogo"]);

    $result = $sql -> execute();

    if ($result) {
      $message = "Customer record was updated";
    } else {
      $message = "The Customer record was not updated";
    }
  }

  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "<div class='notification container'><p>An error occured: " . $e -> getMessage() . "</p></div>";
  }

  $conn = null;
}

if (isset($_POST["updateTeam"])) {
  updateTeam($_POST["teamID"]);
}
```

and here is my markup:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <label>Team ID</label>
  <input type="text" name="teamID" placeholder="9" value="<?php echo $teamID; ?>">
  <label>Team name</label>
  <input type="text" name="teamName" placeholder="Watson's Bay Warriors" value="<?php echo $teamName; ?>">
  <label>Team logo (optional)</label>
  <input type="text" name="teamLogo" placeholder="Blob" value="<?php echo $teamLogo; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="insertTeam" value="Add">
  <input type="submit" name="getTeam" value="Get">
  <input type="submit" name="updateTeam" value="Update">
  <input type="submit" name="deleteTeam" value="Delete">
</form>
```

I have similar functions in place that allow me to add, get and delete and have no issues.

Comment: Where is $val being binded to teamid?

Have you tried
`$sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Team SET teamName=:teamName, teamLogo=:teamLogo, WHERE teamID=:teamID")` ?

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing.  You seem to be injecting $val directly into your query, but your code expects a placeholder of `:teamID`.   I don't see anywhere else where `$val` is used, so what is `$val`?

Comment: I've added the `$_POST` conditional. I should have earlier to explain `$val`.

Comment: @Michael, I tried `$sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Team SET teamName=:teamName, teamLogo=:teamLogo, WHERE teamID=:teamID");`  and got the error: "An error occured: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE teamID='9'' at line 1"

Comment: Get rid of the comma before WHERE

Comment: @danMad,  you should name `$val` something like `$teamID` then.   A developer reading your code should know what a variable is by its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"UPDATE Team SET teamName=:teamName, teamLogo=:teamLogo WHERE teamID=:teamID")
```

Remove the comma before the WHERE clause

Comment: Quick side note, if ID is being pulled from your DB and you don't want people changing it, set your HTML to

`<input type="text" name="teamID" placeholder="9" value="<?php echo $teamID; ?>" readonly />`

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
 $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Team SET teamName=:teamName, teamLogo=:teamLogo, WHERE teamID=" . $val);

 $sql -> bindValue(":teamID", $_POST["teamID"]);
 $sql -> bindValue(":teamName", $_POST["teamName"]);
 $sql -> bindValue(":teamLogo", $_POST["teamLogo"]);
```

Why is teamID =" .$val but you bind the param teamID to a post value? Could that be the error?

Comment: I attempted `$sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Team SET teamName=:teamName, teamLogo=:teamLogo, WHERE teamID=:teamID");` with no success